# Como somar os valores dos checkbox ao clicar em cima do card

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, estou tentando fazer um script para que quando o usuário clicar em cima do card, somar o valor do checkbox.

O script funciona assim: Toda vez que usuário clicar em um determinado card (débito), o input fica como :checked, e quando clicar novamente o input volta ao seu estado padrão.

Eu queria que, quando o usuário clicar em cima desse card, quando o input ficar como :checked, somar o valor do mesmo (como se fosse um carrinho de compras).

Esse é o código que tenho, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o sistema de soma e subtração dos valores. Podem me ajudar?

```
  $(".debitos").find(".card").click(function () {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).removeClass("active");

  $(this).find('.selectDebitCheck').prop('checked', false);
  var total =  $(this).find('.selectDebitCheck:checked').get().reduce(function (tot, el) {
    return tot - Number(el.value);
  }, 0);

  return console.log(total)

} else {
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(this).find('.selectDebitCheck').prop('checked', true);
  var total = $(this).find('.selectDebitCheck:checked').get().reduce(function (tot, el) {
    return tot + Number(el.value);
  }, 0);
  return console.log(total)
  
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Olá, podes tentar fazer um loop pelas checkboxes e incrementar o valor total..

```
var total = 0;
$(this).find('.selectDebitCheck:checked').each(function(i){
  total += $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não funcionou, mas eu coloquei assim: 

total += ~~$(this).val();

E funcionou, mas ele soma apenas os primeiros números, já os centavos, não faz  nenhuma soma.

Ex:

147,00 (era para ser 147,75)

Comment: Pode me mostrar o html também ? Porque eu criei um modelo base de html para testar e funcionou, pode haver problema no html..